# Использование условий в программировании

Tags: c++, c

Сегодня мне препод выдал то, что "условия - это зло. if,switch - гавно". И нужно как-то делать без этих операторов. Он ведь не прав, да? Я считаю, что условия, циклы, массивы - это самая основа программирования, самое часто использование в коде. А тут мне говорят, что условия нужно стараться избегать. Прав ли препод? Скажите пожалуйста, и не минусуйте)) Я так не считаю)) Просто интересно каким образом можно обойтись без этих операторов, и надо ли это на самом деле? Препод мне на эти вопросы не стал отвечать.

UPD:
У меня просто проверка ОДЗ функции:

```
typedef struct test_dy { int valid=1; double num; } test_dy;
test_dy funcG(int x,int a)
{
    test_dy r;

    if ((20*a*a+23*a*x+6*x*x)==0)
        r.valid = 0;
    else
        r.num = (5*(10*a*a + 31*a*x + 15*x*x))/(20*a*a+23*a*x+6*x*x);

    return r;
}
```

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/214914#214920

И да, много `if`'ов, тем более `switch` часто бывают следствием плохой архитектуры.

Comment: @VladD это Вы про винды?

@mctrane 

1. Препод всегда прав.
2. Если препод не прав -- см. п. 1

Comment: @alexlz: А что в архитектуре форточек не так? Я про пример по [ссылке](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Comment: Вот я апдейтил, чем здесь if зло?

Comment: @VladD да я вообще-то про учебники (Петцольда помним?) по winapi/win32api. winmain с огромным switch внутрях

Да, а ещё. Если условия -- зло, то pattern matching (пролог/эрланг/ML'и/хаскел и т.д.) -- это тоже зло, или нет?

Comment: @mctrane зло в тексте (по-моему) -- два раза вычисляется знаменатель. Не из-за машинной эффективности (компилятор соптимизирует), а из-за возможности ошибки при повторном наборе/исправлении в одном из двух мест. такие вещи лучше писать один раз -- спокойнее.

Comment: @mctrane: Зло, вместе с полем `valid`. Вы должны вместо возвращения невалидного значения выбросить исключение.

@alexlz: А, да, стандартная WndProc, нарушает все мыслимые каноны программирования.

Comment: >Сегодня мне препод выдал то, что "условия - это зло. if,switch - гавно".

Прямо так и сказал?

Comment: Ну, конечно, можно вычислить знаменатель один раз, но IMHO фактически без условного выражения все равно  не обойтись. Даже если написать так:

    r.num = (r.valid = 20*a*a+23*a*x+6*x*x) ? 
              (5*(10*a*a + 31*a*x + 15*x*x)) / r.valid : 0;
    return r;

@mctrane, а вообще надо просто стараться **писать как можно понятней** (думаю, эти мои строчки, как раз не очень понятны), а заботу об эффективной загрузке конвейера лучше предоставить компилятору...

Comment: >(думаю, эти мой клд, как раз не очень понятен

думаю, этот пример сугубо индивидуален. Я, скажем, люблю тернарный оператор за его краткость, и где есть возможность, пишу его вместо if, но знаю людей, кто его на дух не переносит за непонятность и неочевидность.

   Однако если вышеозначенный препод имел в виду именно тернарный оператор в качестве замены if, то у меня возникают серьезные опасения по поводу его адекватности

Comment: Добавлю к обсуждению свои пять копеек. Код "без" условных переходов можно писать на языках, поддерживающих паттерн-мэтчинг, (например, Haskell)

    p :: a -> Bool
    f :: a -> b
    f x = g x (p x)
    g :: a -> Bool -> b
    g x true = y1
    g x false = y2

"без" в кавычках, потому что хотя `if` или `case` в коде нет, при компиляции подобного кода уже на первом этапе (в промежуточном языке — Core) появится `case`.

Comment: @VladD я не нашёл другого способа возвращать сообщение от том, что не входит ОДЗ, ведь если возвращать 0, то тогда если вдруг функция будет равна нулю, то выплавит сообщение о том, что не подходит под ОДЗ, хотя это не так.

Comment: @mctrane, очень просто - в ф-ции кидаете `throw` с типом исключения, а в ф-ции, вызывающей `funcG`, оборачиваете вызов в блок `try` и обрабатываете исключение, если оно случилось, в блоке `catch`. Больше информации можно получить по ключевому слову SEH (структурная обработка исключений)

Comment: @mctrane, а по простому такую функцию (с проверкой valid) можно написать так

    double funcG (int x, int a, int *valid) {
      double d = 20*a*a+23*a*x+6*x*x;
         
      return *valid = (d != 0.0) ? (5*(10*a*a + 31*a*x + 15*x*x)) / d : 0;
    }

(Но с if-ами будет понятней) и вызывать так

    ...
    int valid;
    double res = funcG(1, 2, &valid);
    if (valid) {
       ....
    }

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Если преподаватель говорит, что делать то-то и то-то плохо, но при этом не говорит, почему плохо, и как нужно делать, чтобы было хорошо, то он точно ошибается. Ошибается именно как преподаватель, поскольку его задача не просто донести те или иные знания, но еще и донести их так, чтобы студент понял их полезность. А для этого нужно утруждать себя объяснениями. Все-таки программирование - не религия  и не магия (даже несмотря на то, что некоторым оно кажется страшным колдунством), а потому любое утверждение требует обоснования и не может быть принято на веру.

Конкретно по сабжу. Фраза вашего препода кажется вырванной из контекста, скорее всего речь шла о чем-то конкретном - очень сложно поверить, что преподаватель искренне считает, что нужно свести к минимуму использование одной из элементарных конструкций программирования, и в самом лучшем случае это выглядит как экономия на спичках. Если же все именно так, как вы описываете, то у вашего преподавателя крайне странные взгляды на написание кода.

Answer (score 7):

Считать, что `if` это зло может только конченый ид**т.

В алгоритмическом программировании есть 3 управляющие конструкции:

1. Следование (в алгоритмических языках обычно отсутствует в явном виде и задается неявно в виде порядка вызова операторов). Есть еще и подвергнутый остракизму оператор `goto` - но это отдельная песня.
2. Цикл
3. Ветвление

Где-то даже есть такая теорема, что любой алгоритм можно выразить с помощью этих трех конструкций - то есть это минимальный набор необходимый для программирования.

Столь явное отторжение оператора ветвления только свидетельствует в пользу отстутствия у препода нормального фундаментального образования.

**Update:** а вот и ссылка на [теорему Бёма-Якопини](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8), которая и утверждает необходимость 3-х управляющих конструкций для алгоритмизации. На этом фундаменте и строятся все современные алгоритмические языки программирования.

Comment: Ну, можно обойтись и без циклов, с одним лишь goto и if'ами, но это ведь не значит, что использование goto стоит поощрять. Можно написать код и без приватных полей, но делать все поля публичными всё равно «плохо».

Comment: @VladD я конечно понимаю, что на ассемблере вообще можно обойтись одним `JNZ` *(jump-no-zero)*, но речь то идет о более общих конструкциях

Answer (score 6):

Если он считает, что можно и нужно делать без этих ифов, то пусть покажет как. На то он и преподаватель.

Comment: Да, вряд ли он имел в виду моделирование `if`-а `while`-ом и дополнительными переменными :)

Comment: Это ерунда. В циклах все равно имплицитно применяются условные переходы.

Comment: Это я о синтаксических конструкциях языка, а не о машинных командах.

Comment: Как я понял, препод к имел в виду, что условные переходы как раз на низком уровне могут создать проблемы для работы процессора и замедлить выполнение программы.

Comment: goto вообще везде пишут что плохая вещь и нужно её избегать

Comment: >goto вообще везде пишут что плохая вещь и нужно её избегать

а при чем тут goto? Если говорить об ассемблере, то там goto как такового нет (хотя есть куча самых различных переходов, наличие которых там оправдано). А избегать его следует в высокоуровневых языках, где имеются более удобные и прозрачные средства, например тот же if

Comment: @DreamChild

> А избегать его следует в высокоуровневых языках, где имеются более удобные и прозрачные средства, например тот же if

Ну, не совсем. goto можно использовать в том случае, если код с ним проще. Иначе лучше писать структурно с использованием if-while-for-break-continue...

Comment: я не утверждаю, что его нужно избегать всегда. Есть случаи, где его применение  оправдано. Однако соотношение цена/качество при его использовании чаще всего не в пользу goto

Answer (score 3):

Преподаватель отчасти прав, видимо у него есть опыт реальной работы с реальным кодом. Каждый `if` - потенциальный костыль, к тому же затрудняющий чтение кода. Число ветвлений должно быть разумно минимизировано и/или отдано на откуп компилятору.

Если есть желание, то взгляните на возможные реализации паттерна "Посетитель".

Полностью согласен с мнением, что много `if'ов` есть следствие плохой архитектуры.

Comment: > Каждый if - потенциальный костыль

В этом месте так и хочется обобщить и сказать: "любой код - это потенциальный костыль" :)

Comment: Согласен, что преподаватель прав, но только отчасти. К ответам участников хотелось бы добавить, что любой оператор if сбивает конвеер процессора и программа начинает выполняться медленнее (проверено на собственном опыте).
Обобщив все ответы:
Оператор if плох, если:
- используется неоправданно интенсивно
- следствие неправильной архитектуры

Comment: >юбой оператор if сбивает конвеер процессора и программа начинает выполняться медленнее (проверено на собственном опыте)

вы это серьезно, или шутите, надеюсь?

Comment: Вообще говоря, комментарий @progzdeveloper имеет смысл, например, если речь идет о всяких там `GPU,` где цена бранчинга может быть [действительно большой.](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter34.html)

Comment: скажем так, комментарий г-на @progzdeveloper имеет смысл в одном случае из миллиона, а вообще выглядит как нечто голословное (весьма хотелось бы увидеть от него примеры падения производительности, "проверенные на собственном опыте")Кроме того, в наше время большинство программистов занимается не низкоуровневым кодингом на Си вперемешку с асмом, а потому было бы любопытно увидеть пример сколько-нибудь серьезной программы, написанной без if. И желательно без операций, еще более трудоемких, чем if. А пока что это похоже на совет использовать при ходьбе только левую ногу, чтобы правая не уставала

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать: Преждевременная оптимизация — источник холивара в каментах.

Comment: Во-первых: я не предлагаю отказаться от оператора if вовсе и не понимаю с чего уважаемые коллеги так решили. 
Во-вторых: не понимаю при чем здесь преждевременная оптимизация: вопрос ТС имеет общий характер, и поэтому, если мы хотим дать полный и развернутый ответ, то про такие вещи, наверное, стоит упомянуть.
В-третьих: я не очень понимаю к чему здесь GPU, ведь сказанное мной в комментарии относится ко всем процессорам и проистекает из принципов организации кеша и обработки процесссором данных.

Comment: Что касается примера из жизни: в разрабатываемом программном комплексе очень интенсивно использовалась хеш-функция, вычисляющая хеш от строки - очевидно, что это "узкое место", влияющее на производительность всего комплекса. По требованиям заказчика комплекс должен был обрабатывать как минимум до 3 Тб данных в день.  Используемая хеш-функция не давала такой производительности, поскольку внутри содержался оператор if, который препятствовал попаданию исходной строки в кеш L1. Взяв другую хеш-функцию, которая не использует ветвления вовсе, я получил прирост производительности примерно в 2 раза.

Comment: это конечно весьма замечательная история (без иронии...хотя нет, всё же с ней) однако, повторю, такие ситуации имеют место быть в одном случае из миллиона, более того, подобный низкоуровневый код - это вообще отдельная тема. Само по себе утверждение о вредности if будет неверным в остальных 999 999 случаях, и просто дает ТСу (который уж явно не занимается вышеописанными описанными манипуляциями с кэшем процессора) неверную картину о "вредности" условных операторов

Comment: > Используемая хеш-функция не давала такой производительности, поскольку внутри содержался оператор if, который препятствовал попаданию исходной строки в кеш L1.

Очень интересно было б послушать всю историю от начала до конца (с момента обнаружения проблемы до поиска путей ее устранения). Но мне кажется, что этот конкретный случай - частный. Тем более было б занятно, если на другом процессоре все попадало в L1 cache даже с исходным кодом.

Comment: @progzdeveloper, вот об этой задаче и **таком** влиянии на производительность всей программы **именно хэш функции** поподробнее, если можно (можно даже код обеих функций привести).

Comment: Если есть такая заинтересованность, то нужно создать отдельную тему и там обсуждать, а не наводить флуд в комментариях. Кроме того я никому своего мнения не навязываю, так что не вижу предмета для споров)))

Comment: @progzdeveloper, вот и откройте. 

Правда же интересно, что же это за *программный комплекс*, на который так сильно может влиять  функция хэширования.

Answer (score 3):

Есть разные подходы в программировании. Нужно уметь выбирать конкретный в применении к конкретной задаче. Также понятно, что впадать в фанатизм и использовать во всех случаях одну и ту же парадигму - неверно. Давайте вспомним оператор `goto` и холивары, которые он вызывает. Ведь действительно любой цикл (`while{...}`, `do{...}while`, `for(...){...}`) можно переписать как `if` + `goto`, но код от этого красивее, более поддерживаемым, более расширяемым, более понятным не станет. А наоборот - сколько угодно.

Касательно обилия if'ов. Без условного оператора в принципе никакой сколько-угодно сложный алгоритм не написать. Но делать код типа `if (a==1) ... else if (a==2) ... else if (a==3)` просто вредно. Как минимум потому что есть конструкция switch - case для таких случаев. А как максимум, потому что существуют другие способы реализовать то же самое. Например, хэш-таблицы, массивы, косвенная адресация, тот же упомянутый паттерн "Посетитель".

В любом случае, полезно всю работу по кодогенерации сгрузить на компилятор, а самому заниматься решением задачи на максимально высоком уровне, а не лезть на самый нижний. Иначе можно писать на том же ассемблере вообще без циклов, а с одними `CMP`, `LOOP` и `JMP`/`JE`/`JBE`/*. Только зачем?

Что же касается кодогенерации - да, преподаватель прав. Современные процессоры НЕ ЛЮБЯТ условные переходы. И при прочих равных линейный код будет быстрее. Но опять же - это не должно быть головной болью программиста. Преждевременная оптимизация - зло. Напишите сначала рабочий алгоритм, а потом начните его тюнить и оптимизировать. По крайней мере, будет эталон с чем сравнить :-) когда что-то перестанет получаться. К тому же компиляторы оптимизирующие и должны вместо того кода высокого уровня, который пишет программист, генерировать наиболее оптимальный код для конкретной платформы. Но жизнь как всегда вносит коррективы. И это уже не для junior'ов, а для серьезных пацанов 8-)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю что преподаватель ошибается.
Такое бывает.
По вашему вопросу сам заинтересовался, и нагуглил вот это: [Программирование без использования условных конструкций](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124878/)

Comment: Спасибо)) Надо будет поспорить с ним))

Answer (score 0):

ну тогда любой код зло ! и while, а уж printf то какое зло ! просто не реальное !
но в тоже время нельзы довадить код до фанатического поклонения if, и увидев код типа приведенного ниже я бы тоже сказал что if это зло...

```
if(a == '1')
...
elseif(a == '2')
...
elseif(a == '3')
...
elseif(a == '4')
...
else
...
```

Comment: нет, там просто проверка ОДЗ функции, если знаменатель равен 0, то r.valid = 0; иначе r.valid=1;r.num=x/x+2x

Answer (score 0):

Прочитав вопрос и делая вывод из всего пришел к выводу что преподаватель просто пошутил наверное. Но и это можно обойти с помощью ассемблерных вставок(инструкций для процессора) внедренных в сишный код которые вполне можно использовать вместо if'овских переходах и тп, т.к. потому что это уже не оператор сравнения а блок инструкций. хотя я могу ошибаться в терминологии, не судите строго

Answer (score 0):

Если знаменатель ноль, то и числитель ноль. Значит, при r.num = 0 нет корней.

```
test_dy funcG1(int x,int a)
{
    test_dy r;

    r.num = (5*(10*a*a + 31*a*x + 15*x*x))/(20*a*a+23*a*x+6*x*x + (int) !(bool) (20*a*a+23*a*x+6*x*x));

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых в СИ нету типа бул, только в СИ++, во-вторых если вдруг функция будет равнятся нулю, то выведет что не подходит под ОДЗ

Comment: В метках есть "с++"  
На C99 добавляешь #include <stdbool.h> и можно пользоваться bool


    Запись r = funcG(0, 0);

возвращает ноль, а не выдает ошибку, если Вы это имели ввиду.